# Finding duplicate members in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have come across a problem in writing a query to find duplicate members in a table. I have tried to simplify the problem with a sample table and data.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
S_ID VARCHAR2(10),
PARAM VARCHAR2(10),
VALUE VARCHAR2(10)
);


INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('1', 'NAME', 'A');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('1', 'AGE', '15');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('1', 'SEX', 'M');

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('2', 'NAME', 'B');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('2', 'AGE', '16');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('2', 'SEX', 'M');

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('3', 'NAME', 'A');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('3', 'AGE', '15');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (S_ID, PARAM, VALUE) VALUES ('3', 'SEX', 'M');
```

Here items with S_ID 1 and 3 are same.

Comment: you can create combined unique key for PARAM and VALUE fields

Comment: I have tried to simplify the problem with this same table, for the original problem, I cannot change the keys at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to find duplicate values in one field:

```
SELECT fieldName FROM TableName
GROUP BY FieldName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I think you answered it before I updated my question with the sample table.

Comment: So you mead IDs where ALL records within that ID are duplicated in another ID group?

Answer (score 1):

You mean this? :

```
select colname, count(colname) from TableName
    Group by colname Having (count(colname) > 1)
```

Comment: I think you answered it before I updated my question with the sample table.